# Turning 'bytes' into 'str': Why is a '\' added to '\n' and such?

Tags: python, string, replace, python-2to3

I read various lines from a CSV file like this:

```
f1 = open(current_csv, 'rb')
table = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
```

So essentially any single line in `table` is something like this:

```
line = b' G\xe4rmanword:           123,45\r\n'
```

which `type` tells me is `bytes`, but I need to work around with `.replace` so I'm turning it into a string: `line = str(line)`, but now `line` turned into

```
"b' G\\xe4rmanword:           123,45\\r\\n'"
```

with and added `\` before every `\`. However, with `print(line)`, they don't show up, but if I want to turn `\xe4` into `ae` (alternative way of writing ä) with `line = line.replace('\xe4', 'ae')` this just does nothing. Using `'\\xe4'` works, however. But I would have expected that the first one just turns `\\xe4` into `\ae` instead of just doing nothing, and the second option, while working, relies on my defining a *new* definition for the replacement for *ä*, both of which I'd rather avoid.

**So I'm trying to understand where the extra backslash comes from and how I can avoid it to start with, instead of having to fix it in my postprocessing.** I have the feeling that something changed between python2 and 3, since the original csv reader is a python2 script I had translated with `2to3`.

Comment: Don't do this: `line = str(line)`. You want to *decode* the `bytes` object into a `str` object, passing it to the `str` object constructor just gives you the *string representation of the bytes object*, which is not what you want. You probably should just open the file in text mode, so `f1 = open(current_csv, 'r')` so `'r'` instead of `'rb'`

Comment: Yes, there are changes between Python 2 and 3. You can read those related to strings them [here][1]


  [1]: https://medium.com/better-programming/strings-unicode-and-bytes-in-python-3-everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-27dc02ff2686

Comment: @L3viathan yep, my bad

Comment: I think I actively chose `rb` since `r` can't deal with umlauts like ä, which I'm dealing with later on (which now fails).

Comment: @JC_CL um, yes, `'r'` can deal with that just fine, you just need to provide it the correct encoding. so `f1 = open(current_csv, 'r', encoding='latin1')`

Comment: You're right. that's probably the correct way to to it, but for working with the historical thing, the answer also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since Python3 uses Unicode for all strings, the semantics of many string-related functions including `str` have changed compared to Python2. In this particular case, you need to use second argument to `str` providing the encoding used in your input `bytes` value (which, judging from the use of German language, is 'latin1'):

```
unicode_string = str(line, 'latin1')
```

Alternatively you can do the same using

```
unicode_string = line.decode('latin1')
```

And you'd probably want the `\r\n` removed, so add `.rstrip()` to that.
Besides, a more elegant solution for reading the file is:

```
with open(current_csv, 'rb') as f1:
    table = f1.readlines()
```

(so no need for `close()`)

Comment: "(which, judging from the use of German language, is 'latin1')" that's not really a reasonable inference. utf8 etc handles German language characters just fine, it's simply a different encoding.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is reasonable. The charset in question obviously is **not ** UTF-8 nor any other kind of Unicode encoding, it is one of legacy 8-bit encodings. And for German the most likely 8-bit encoding is 'latin1' (ISO/IEC 8859-1) or possibly 'cp1252' a.k.a. 'windows-1252', but most certainly not, for example, 'latin2'

Comment: Sure, my point was that simply "German => latin1" isn't a good inference.

Comment: Thanks, that works. In my case, according to `file` it's `ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators` which isn't really clear, but `cp1252` works for me. Also, Yamila Omars link in the comments to question was very helpful in understanding what happened.